# CSV import parse into xml tree

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv, powershell-ise

Well this one is a tricky one for my powershell experience. If anyone can help that would be great.

What I have:

```
$csvdata = Import-CSV 'file.csv'

|  Location             | Description
| /Texas/Bryan          | Pond Anup
| /Texas/Bryan          | Pond Charlie
| /Texas/Killen/        | Lake Snoopy
```

example: output.xml

```
<groups>
    <group name="Texas">
        <site name="Bryan">Pond Anup</site>
    </group>
</groups>
```

What I am trying to do is loop thru the csv import and do the following:

- If Texas does not exist create
- If Texas does exist but not Bryan create child to Texas as Bryan
- If Both exist add child to Bryan as a site node

I am new to powershell and this has nothing to do with AD as I seen lots of examples out there for this. I am hoping there is a script already created or a cmdlet that I can call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic loop and logic you'd need to use to accomplish this:

```
$csvdata = Import-CSV "file.csv"
$outfile = "output.xml"

"<groups>" | Out-File $outfile #start groups

$lastGroup = ""
$lastSite = ""

$csvdata | foreach {
    $group = ($_.Location.Split('/'))[1]
    $site = ($_.Location.Split('/'))[2]
    $child = $_.Description
    if ($group -ne $lastGroup) #if we're not in the same group
    {
        if ($lastGroup -ne "") {"    </group>" | Out-File $outfile -Append }
        "    <group name=`"" + $group + "`">" | Out-File $outfile -Append
    }
    if ($site -ne $lastSite) #if we're not in the same site
    {
        if ($lastSite -ne "") {"        </site>" | Out-File $outfile -Append}
        "        <site name=`"" + $site + "`">" | Out-File $outfile -Append
    }
    # now write child:
    "            <child name=`"" + $child + "`"></child>" | Out-File $outfile -Append

    $lastGroup = $group
    $lastSite = $site
}
#write final end tags
"        </site>" | Out-File $outfile -Append
"    </group>" | Out-File $outfile -Append 
"</groups>" | Out-File $outfile -Append #end groups
```

The code will give you output like this:

```
<groups>
    <group name="Texas">
        <site name="Bryan">
            <child name="Pond Anup"></child>
            <child name="Pond Charlie"></child>
        </site>
        <site name="Killen">
            <child name="Lake Snoopy"></child>
        </site>
    </group>
</groups>
```

Hopefully that gets you started in the right direction.